# Determining item ability scores for an intelligent item from the book of Eldritch Might

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, character-creation, crafting

The book states:

[image]

Does this mean that if you spend 50gp all ability scores the item has increase by 1?

And if you spend 400gp all abilities increase by +4? etc.

To me this seems far too cheap and I am thinking it is meant to read that spending the money increases one ability score but it seems a bit vague.

On the other hand as the item only gets 2d6 die to determine ability scores instead of the usual 4d6 less the lowest die roll I could see where this may be implemented so that their scores are comparable to a player character.

As a side note this is an item being created as a player character for one of my players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer would be that it means each cost is to increase a SINGLE stat by that amount, which is still a really good rate.

Additionally, yes, the cheap cost is used to defray the fact they are inferior on all counts anyway.